# working with pseudo-elements jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML table with some `<tr>` and `<td>`, and I need to set some attributes to certain `<td>` elements. So, the problem is:

If I write the selector [**this way**](http://jsfiddle.net/JTyju/3/):

```
$("table tr:not(table tr:first)").css("background","#ccc");
```

it works fine, but if I try to use a specific table, nothing happens:

```
$("#tableTit tr:not(#tableTit tr:first)").css("background","#ccc");
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @Loktar yeah yeah, i was just testing some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify the ID a second time. Just do this:

```
$('#tableTit tr:not(:first)').css(...);
```

Or as @bažmegakapa suggests in the comments:

```
$('#tableTit tr').not(':first').css(...);
```

Comment: `$('#tableTit tr').not(':first')` is more effective though.

Comment: `:first` is a jQuery extension, a special selector. These are not supported by the native `querySelectorAll()` DOM method, so jQuery has to fire its own selector engine. Always try to separate native selectors and extension selectors. Read more on the [manual page](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).

Comment: Ah, good to know. For some reason, I always assumed that jQuery was smarter than that. Thanks.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo It would be hard and error-prone for jQuery, and also a big performance nightmare if it had to analyze and rebuild all your selectors. The programmer should know how to make it work the best possible way (that is why we are not replaced by monkeys yet). The tool is not responsible for irresponsible coding.